# Insert a row below the last row of a Table and keep the same format and formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a row below the last row of data in a table, so far I've managed add a number of rows after prompting the user for it, but I want to add the new row(s) at the end of the table instead of at the beginning of it, this is my code so far:

```
Dim myTbl As ListObject
Dim x As String
Dim i As Long
Dim newRow As Range
Dim sngCell As Range

    Set myTbl = Sheets("Invoice").ListObjects(1)
    x = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")
    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To CInt(x)
        Set newRow = myTbl.ListRows.Add(1).Range
        With newRow
            .Offset(1).Copy
            ' .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            For Each sngCell In newRow
                If Not (sngCell.HasFormula) Then
                    sngCell.ClearContents
                End If
            Next
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`ListRows.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows.add) documentation, concerning the optional `Position` parameter:

> If *Position* is not specified, a new bottom row is added.

Remove the `1` in `Set newRow = myTbl.ListRows.Add(1).Range`.